# PowerShell: Change default output cmdlet

Tags: powershell, logging, output, powershell-cmdlet

Afternoon folks,
I'm sorry the title is poorly written, I wasn't sure how to word it.

What I'm looking to do, if possible (without a bunch of `If/Else` or `switch` statements) is to change what cmdlet for outputting text is used. I have a logging module I've written and am working on inputting into my scripts. I'd like to however add a switch parameter to my scripts, (i.e `-EnableLogging`) that when called uses my logging module instead of `Write-Output` or `Write-Host` as examples.

Is this possible without doing a `If/Else` or `Switch` checking if that tag was enabled everytime I want to output to the console?

Theres not much of a code to see but:

```
.\script.ps1 -EnableLogging
use Write-Log (my module, instead of Write-Output)
```

vs

```
.\script.ps1
use Write-Output (instead of Write-Log)
```

I'm curious as to if theres a way to change/specify this besides doing this for every output

```
.\script.ps1 -EnableLogging

Switch($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('EnableLogging'){
    true {Write-Log "hello world"}
    false {Write-Output "hello world"}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a minimal code example of what you currently have

Comment: add parameters to you script, e.g. the parameter (switch) EnableLogging. in the script you can then do ```If (EnableLogging){}```. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I added code, but there's not much, it was mainly an 'if possible' kind of question. 
@Toni I know I can do ``If\Else`` or ``switch`` statements for each output, I was just curious if there was more of a global way to change it instead of adding like 7 extra lines of code for each output statement

Comment: What I usually do, is put all script code into a script block or function and then redirect (merge) all output streams into the *success* stream using operator `*>&1` to provide a single point of logging. You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422625/7571258). It would be just a matter of inserting an `if` statement that checks for `-EnableLogging` parameter and writes to a file, where the output is currently written (e. g. before the `"$($PSStyle.Reset)[$date] $line"` line in the 1st sample code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this might do what you're looking for, basically you would be using `| & $command` on each output line, however what "command" to run is only checked once. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
function Testing {
    param([switch] $EnableLogging)

    $command = 'Write-Output'
    if($EnableLogging.IsPresent) {
        $command = 'Write-Host'
    }

    'Hello World!' | & $command
    0..5 | ForEach-Object { "$_. Testing..." } | & $command
}
```

Now we can test if it works, if `-EnableLogging` is not present we should be able to capture output, in other words, `Write-Output` is being used, else `Write-Host`:

```
# works, output is captured in `$tryCapture`
$tryCapture = Testing
# also works, output goes directly to Information Stream
$tryCapture = Testing -EnableLogging
```